# New api to get user's birthday and gender?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Knowing that the google plus/person api is deprecated to use in android, I'm wondering what is the alternatives for getting this info?

I can get the name/email and all that GoogleSignInAccount has to offer -  but not gener and birthday.

Any alternatives?

Comment: Ask the user for it?

Comment: so... you dont know then

Comment: what scope have you authenticated with?